# Kubernetes networking: is service information stored in every node's IPTable?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Can someone tell me why the service hop won't become a single point of failure?

In [Kubernete Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/_print/), I see an hop of Service between the client and Pods: [image]

I guess all service's (let's say there are 5000 of services and each service has 3 Pods) routing info are stored in the IPTable of each node?

Comment: It's up to the CNI on how it manages everything.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes services connect a set of pods to an abstracted service name and IP address. Services provide discovery and routing between pods.

It depends upon the CNI which you are using and what type of network it will use. Every network plugin has a different approach for how a Pod IP address is assigned (IPAM), how iptables rules and cross-node networking are configured, and how routing information is exchanged between the nodes.

Comment: What is the default CNI? Say if I don’t do any advanced setup on AWS EKS or Google GKE, what CNI am I going to use in the cluster?

Comment: If it is minikube  by default Minikube runs on Docker default bridge-network and for other k8's you will decide and config which CNI to use